# Ограничение ввода до и после запятой C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

В textBox (keyPress) ввод максимально 10 символов цифровых до запятой (000 000 0000) и ограничение символов после запятой в количестве 2 символов, когда я ввожу после запятой эти 2 символа то получается вот так (000 000 0000,00), но когда мне надо отредактировать числа до запятой то получается вот (000 000 0,00), т.е. видно что их тоже 10 символов, но к сожалению формула уже считает все десять символов и до и после запятой. А надо чтобы было 10 символов до запятой, ну и соответственно если надо добавить 2 символа после запятой. Не судите, как смог написать, уж лучше не поясняется.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.IndexOf(",") > 0)
            if (textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.Text.IndexOf(",")).Length > 3)
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length - 0;
            }
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9'))
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length == 10 && textBox1.Text.Length <= 10)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            return;
        }
            // Точку заменим запятой
            if (e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                e.KeyChar = ',';
            }
            if (e.KeyChar == ',')
            {
                if ((textBox1.Text.IndexOf(',') != -1) || (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)) // Не более одной запятой и
                {                                                                      // запятая не может быть первым символом.
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                return;
            }
            if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
                {
                    // button1.Focus();
                    return;
                }
            }
            e.Handled = true; // true - остальные символы запрещены
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как насчёт использования `MaskedTextBox` или `NumericUpDown`?

Comment: Да тут дело в коде,судя по всему вот здесь: if (textBox1.Text.Length == 10 && textBox1.Text.Length <= 10) никак не понять мне, что ещё надо добавить или изменить.